# nginx ingress - unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes

I am running nginx ingress on my kubernetes 1.9 cluster. Using internal singed certificate for the application URL, I have include root & intermediate certificate part of the TLS secretes.

From my nginx log file, I see this message frequently.

```
backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate.
```

How to get more details about this error message?

error message:

```
E0129 01:11:39.582118       7 backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate.
E0129 01:11:39.582689       7 backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate.
E0129 01:11:39.583031       7 backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate.
E0129 01:11:39.583308       7 backend_ssl.go:139] unexpected error generating SSL certificate with full intermediate chain CA certs: Invalid certificate.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some certificates don't support it. You need to set --enable-ssl-chain-completion = false . Then it stops

Comment: after adding this flag, message stop showing up `--enable-ssl-chain-completion=false`